# No method 'addPlugin' at cordova.js

Tags: android, cordova

When I integrate SMS inbox_sent access Plugin into applicaton, it shows following error:

01-20 15:03:46.615: I/Web Console(1897): Failed to run constructor: TypeError: Object # has no method 'addPlugin' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:317

Please suggest me the solution to overcome the problem

Comment: I am facing same issue, can anyone please help me.